# spline approximation with specified number of intervals

Tags: r, matlab, octave, scilab, maxima

So - edited because some of us thought that this question is off-topic.

I need to build spline (approximation) on 100 points in one of environments listed in tags. But I need it with exact number of intervals (maximum of 6 intervals - separate equations - in whole domain). Packages / libraries in R and Maxima which I know let me for building spline on this points but with 25-30 intervals (separate equations). Does anyone know how to build spline with set number of intervals without coding whole algorithm all over again?

Comment: a spline with exact number of segment? I do not understand this unclear sentence, can you reformulate? By the way typing something like 'R spline' in any web search engine will lead you to this kind of page https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/smooth.spline.html....

Comment: Same as @colonel-beauvel I do not understand your exact problem, but the basics of spline interpolation in Scilab are given [here](http://wiki.scilab.org/Overview%20of%20interpolation%20in%20Scilab)

Comment: Perhaps if you added a simple example [How to Make a Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) to you post, it would help clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Maybe I used wrong word for it.
I mean that I can use spline which consists only e.g. ten polynomials.
I have 100 points and I want to build spline on it, but it has to consist at a maximum ten polynomials in that domain.

Comment: Default method in maxima gave me a spline with about 25 sections.

Comment: By the way, what function did you use in Maxima?

Comment: For building a spline: cspline.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for might be described as "local regression" or "localized regression"; searching for those terms might turn up some hits.

I don't know if you can find exactly what you've described. But implementing it doesn't seem too complicated: (1) Split the domain into N intervals (say N=10). For each interval, (2) make a list of the data in the interval, (3) fit a low-order polynomial (e.g. cubic) to the data in the interval using least squares.

If that sounds interesting to you, I can go into details, or maybe you can work it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I considered this approach but it would probably result in discontinuities on  bounds of intervals.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You will have to put in constraints to make the ends match up. I can think of 2 ways to do that. (1) Add a term for each pair of matched ends which penalizes the difference between p[i - 1](m[i]) and p[i](m[i]) where p[i - 1] and p[i] are the polynomials on the left and right sides of the match point m[i]. This is a so-called soft constraint. It is less exact but easier to handle. (2) Constrained minimization of sum of squares via augmented Lagrangian method or some other method for constrained optimization. I believe this isn't too hard. I will describe it if you want.

Comment: But then I'll have to code everything by myself, right?
I'll not be able to add these constraints to some method implemented in one of environments listed in tags.

Comment: Maxima has an implementation of the augmented Lagrangian method. It is actually not very complicated -- it amounts to adding a variable penalty term to the function to be minimized and then repeatedly minimizing function + penalty, such that it converges to a minimum of function satisfying the constraints.

Comment: So, what I think that you're trying to suggest me to do:
1. Split the domain (a set of points) into smaller sets.
2. Use kind of procedure:
augmented_lagrangian_method(lsquares_estimates (matrix, [x,y], y = a*x*x*x + b*x*x + c*x + d, [a, b, c, d]), [a, b, c, d], CONSTRAINT, [a0, b0, c0, d0]),
where
CONSTRAINT : y(endOfTheSegment) = yCoordinateOfTheBandPoint

Am I right? ;)

Comment: @bpop Yes, but I think some details would have to be changed -- maybe you mean lsquares_mse instead of lsquares_estimates, and for the constraints, I think you want cubic[i](foo) = cubic[i + 1](foo) where cubic[i] is the i'th function and foo = midpoint between max(i'th x data) and min((i + 1)'th x data). To be honest, I am trying that right now, and I am having trouble getting it to work. So I can't really recommend this approach. Perhaps you'll be able to find an existing library, or take a different approach. Good luck and let us know here how it turns out.

Comment: So I've found an already programmed solution for my problem. ...Invented in 1991. :)
It is called MARS - Multivariate adaptive regression splines
R package called earth: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/earth/index.html
Matlab toolbox called ARESLab: http://www.cs.rtu.lv/jekabsons/regression.html
Thanks Robert for your interest in the problem.

Comment: Terrific, thanks for the update. I heard of MARS long ago and I didn't connect it to your problem.